# How can I figure out which framework was used for build application's (Spotify) UI?

Tags: user-interface, frameworks, reverse-engineering, spotify

I would like to know which framework was used to build Spotify's UI.

Is that possible somehow?
Would decompiling help?

[image]

**EDIT:**

Found that in the assembly. Seems to be something from the .NET or C++ or C# world?

```
C:\BuildAgent\work\89ac9b83199a0548\build\desktop\_win32\Release\spotify.pdb

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity
    version="1.0.0.0"
    processorArchitecture="X86"
    name="Spotify"
    type="win32"
  />
  <description>Spotify</description>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>

  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spotify's UI is built with a combination of a completely custom C++ UI toolkit that was built in-house and HTML5/Javascript using Chromium.

Comment: Thanx for the info! I thought like 1000 times about building desktop applicaitons with HTML5 but I never knew how to start! Maybe I now will try chromium! Do you mean this project? https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/

Comment: Yeah, that's the one.

Comment: @iKenndac you are not using Qt for the interface?